# Kalman smoother equations

Tags: statistics, kalman-filter

I'm trying to find the Kalman filter equations, i.e $\mathbb{E}[X_k \mid y_0,...,y_n]$ with $k \lt n$ by figuring out the law of the the density $p(x_k \mid y_0,...,y_n)$ under the Hidden Markov Chain Model ($X_k$ is a markov chain and conditionally on $(X_{0:n}=(X_0,...,X_n))$, the observations $(Y_{0:n})$ are independent and the observations $i$ only depends on the hidden state $X_i$ : 
\begin{equation}
p(x_{0:n},y_{0:n})=p(x_0)\prod_{i=1}^n p(x_i \mid x_{i-1}) \prod_{i=0}^n p(x_i \mid y_i)
\end{equation}
The thing is, i'm struggling with a preliminary question: that is to prove :
\begin{equation}
p(x_{0:k} \mid x_{k+1}, y_{0:n})=p(x_{0:k} \mid x_{k+1}, y_{0:k})
\end{equation}
Anyone know how to prove it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the reputation to put this as a comment, so I post as an answer.

It follows from the Markov assumptions. The past, $x_{0:k}$, is independent of the future given the present, $x_{k+1}$.

If you draw the graphical model it may be easier to see. Given $x_{k+1}$, $x_{0:k}$ is "blocked" from $y_{k+1}$ and every observation afterwards.

Comment: @Leucippus: I believe it does answer the OP's question on how to prove the result. If the OP requires clarification, then the OP should tell me -- not you.